# iMessage on my MacBook Pro does not show current texts from my iPhone

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, messages

My iMessages on my MacBook Pro have stopped being current as of a month ago. It's now the end of June and it only shows texts from the middle of May.

I noticed my Apple ID was logged out just now (in iMessage on my Mac) so I logged back in, although I never logged out in the first place. So I don't know how long it's been logged out for. Now it's showing some current texts (only from today), but not all that should be an iMessage and texts that were also sent today.

Comment: It won't go back & fetch older messages, only ones from after you signed in.

Comment: What versions of OS X and iOS are on your devices?

Answer (score 1):

iMessages and SMS messages from when you were not signed in will not be shown now that you have signed in. Messages does not retroactively obtain messages. Now that you have signed in, new messages will be delivered correctly.